# Possibility of editing a piece of data on a website using C#.Net Built Desktop Software

Tags: c#, html, .net, browser, webclient

Warm greetings.

I am trying to find out if there is a way of editing/updating something on a website using a piece of software made in C#. 
By this I mean, if the website prompts a user to enter a number for some field and displays it on the site, then can I not carry out the exact same steps in the software so I don't have to go to the website to enter/amend/?

A quick fictional example. I have built a small software related to a random number generator. This software shows two pieces of information independent of each other. One generates any random number by computer and two, shows a number (using a WebClient Class to scrape data from the website) from the website which asks the user to manually enter any random number which then displays on the site. 
Now, is it possible to link these two in a way that when a random number is generated by computer in the software, say number 8, this is then updated on the site which will show it rather than manually going to the site and entering number 8 and then showing it.
Is there a specific class that exists for this?

I am sorry for it being long but I hope I was being specific, at least enough to give you a good idea of what it is I am seeking. I hope I don't have to learn another programming language to implement this in my software. I am guessing I need to be familiar with HTML with CSS at maximum.

Thank You.

UPDATE: Thanks to boaz levinson's post, I have been made to realise this process is called two-way data binding, at least under angular js. My question remains, is there a way of implementing this feature in C# language without learning another?

Comment: "I am trying to find out if there is a way of editing/updating something on a website using a piece of software made in C#" Yes.  However, this is far too vague to provide a meaningful answer.  Unless you can provide some  technical details, there isn't anything more I can tell you.

Comment: I have given an example below to elaborate on that. 
And I would like to thank you for your quick reply.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for how to post a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example of your code in a question.

Comment: Please read https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question/7274

Answer (score 1):

Do you happen to mean two way binding ? 
this can be easily achieved with angular js or (older lib) knockout js 
values that user inserts will appear in another html tag on the screen by editing it's model behind  , and also the computing will update this model , both resulting the same html div \ span to show the latest update . 
see the following for more info , and by the way , angular is not so scary !

[Simple Two Way Binding](http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/basics/twowaydatabinding/)

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to look for the right terminology to explain better and you have come up with just that. Can I implement this two-way binding into C# built software? Or are there any existing classes in C#, maybe even external packages for C#, that can implement this behaviour?

Comment: Angular js means client side javascript code . the learning curve to add this library create a controller model and view is not so steep . you can however do that in c# server side (in an artificial sort of way) , i found this answer for you , maybe it will be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428762/two-way-databinding-in-asp-net